# Failed to open stream: Permission denied on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have the following php code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
    include("config.php");
include('navbar.php');  
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

    $message="";

        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
         $name = $_POST['title'];
                  $description = $_POST['description'];
                  $price= $_POST['price'];
                  $calories=  $_POST['calorie'];
                  $category=  $_POST['category'];
                $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
          $tempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];    
        $folder = "../images/".$filename;
                     $item_id="622434b1fc13ae1418000".rand(000,999);
          $upload = move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder);
```

The page works on localhost just fine using Apache (Xampp) but from AWS elastic beanstalk, it keeps resulting in following errors when uploading image:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../images/catagory.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/web/admin/add-food.php on line 21
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/phpBXgx8L" to "../images/catagory.jpg" in /var/www/html/web/admin/add-food.php on line 21
```

Is this because Elastic beanstalk does not allow for writable system? and if so, we have to use Amazon S3 to store the files instead?

Comment: You can write to filesystem in EB, but its bad practice. Your error is caused by whatever `../images/` points to. What exactly is the absolute path to `images`?

Comment: @Marcin the path to images is: `C:\xampp\htdocs\ROMS\web\Restraurant system\images` where Restaurant system is configured as "admin

Comment: This is not valid EB path. Thus its not clear what you are doing.

Comment: @Marcin oh you mean the images absolute path on EB?

Comment: @Marcin `$root = getcwd(); echo $root;` shows the directory at: `/var/www/html/web/admin`

Comment: Also what is the exact EB platform version that you are using?

Comment: @Marcin i noted that `Restraurant system` directory is set to Read-only. idk if its because its hosted on github, but everytime i change it from read-only it reverts back to read-only...i wonder if this is the reason the permission error occurs?  ive run accross solutions like running `sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/web/admin -R` the problem is idk where to run that command from, the AWS CLI? im using windows system afterall...

Comment: You have to run it on your EB instance, after you ssh into it.

Comment: @Marcin i suppose `Docker AL2 version 3.4.13`